# AnkhSVN Visual Studio Conflict

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, version-control, visualsvn, ankhsvn

I have just installed AnkhSVN for a new project I've been recruited for. The development is taking place in Visual Studio 2010.

Prior to this I had VisualSVN installed - this is still installed.

I have downloaded the source code from SVN however when I try to open the solution I get the following error:

> The active solution or project is controlled by a different source control plug-in than the one you have selected. If you change the source control plugin, the active solution or project will be closed. Do you wish to continue?

I have set the "Current Source Control Option" to "AnkhSVN - Subversion support for Visual Studio" via "Tools -> Options -> Source Control".

I have checked the solution file and I believe this is configured correctly:

```
GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
Svn-Managed = True
Manager = AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
EndGlobalSection
```

This is driving me mad.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens if you choose to continue? Can you also check what SCC provider is active (Tools - Options - Source Control) before opening this project?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to CheckIn the project to your PC through Visual Studio and for that you need a Solution file to open the project. Follow this steps:

**Open Visual Studio -> File -> Subversion -> Open from Subversion -> Then choose the Solution file from your SVN repository -> Choose a directory to create your Working Copy**

If the error persists, you need to check if there is a folder with the same name, in the place where you will get your **Working Copy** or you need to check if exists any Solution file in the **Working Copy** folder.